# Preferences list inside a single MySQL Column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently writing code for a user login script. The script also has an option to enable "IP identification" to check if the IP which the person who logged in, matches with the one which is stored in the MySQL database. I also want people to be able to add multiple IP-Addresses. I'm currently using a simple PHP array for it, like this:

`$IP_array = array("xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx3");`

So it can check if one of the Array values matches one of the given IP Addresses in the database. Problem is; it isn't the most efficient option and it also doesn't support CRUD. I also tried to give every IP it's own column, but that means that I have to make a new column for every single IP address, but it should be unlimited, so that's why I want it to be in a single column.

How do I code a more efficient way to store multiple values in only one column (like an array), which also supports: add values & delete values?

Comment: Too broad a subject, but you want to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data. Add another table with a user ID and IP address columns. Use joins to retrieve matching columns.

Comment: @miken32 Right but, that means that there's a limit for how much IP's users can store (The amount of columns). And that's the problem, it has to be unlimited.

Comment: No, your table has 2 columns. User ID and IP address. One entry for each IP address. Read the article I linked to.

Comment: @miken32 I get it! I'll try that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on my comments above, right now you've got something like this:

```
╔══════════╗
║   User   ║
╠══════════╣
║ ID       ║
╠══════════╣
║ Name     ║
╠══════════╣
║ Address  ║
╚══════════╝
```

Which works fine for a single address. But you want to add more. You could do this:

```
╔══════════╗
║   User   ║
╠══════════╣
║ ID       ║
╠══════════╣
║ Name     ║
╠══════════╣
║ Address1 ║
╠══════════╣
║ Address2 ║
╚══════════╝
```

But as you correctly point out, you would "have to make a new column for every single IP address."

Instead, you should create a new table, so you have this:

```
╔══════════╗        ╔═══════════╗                  
║   User   ║        ║ Addresses ║                  
╠══════════╣        ╠═══════════╣                  
║ ID       ║        ║ UserID    ║                  
╠══════════╣        ╠═══════════╣                  
║ Name     ║        ║ Address   ║                  
╚══════════╝        ╚═══════════╝
```

The ID of the user indicates the relationship between the two, and should be specified as a foreign key on the Address table. When querying, you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Address FROM User U LEFT JOIN Addresses A ON (U.ID = A.UserID) WHERE ID = ?
```

And you'd get one row for each address.

Comment: But what's the value of the "Address" column going to look like? Because that's important for how the user can add/delete Addresses (or IP's in my case).

Comment: It will look like whatever you put into it. Add them as a plain string, or convert to a number on the PHP (ip2long) or MySQL (INET_ATON) side.

Comment: Right! But for example; if a user has two IP-addresses: "123" & "987", how would I do that? Should I just put: ```123 987``` in a column? Because that's hard to delete (if you need to select a specific IP address to delete)

Comment: You're not getting this. One row in the addresses table for EACH ADDRESS.

Comment: Now I get it! So if a user wants to add a new IP address, the PHP script should add a new row via a query with the UserID as a link to the "owner" of the IP address and if you want to delete it, you should target that IP address & the UserID?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.